# Undeterministic array copy in Scala using jdk10

Tags: scala, compiler-optimization

I ran tests of my library using jdk10 and they randomly failed in 50% of cases. I extracted very small fragment of code that reproduce the error and run it in the loop counting failures. Failures count is usually about 100k - 700k for 1M trials.

What I discovered until now:

1. Code works in jdk8 and fails in jdk9 and jdk10
2. When you change the order of second and third line in `addressToBytes` method it works
3. When you inline methods of `SomeOutputStream` it works
4. When you disable last level of java optimization: -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=3 it works
5. When you run this code in debug mode it mostly works.

I use scala 2.12.6 and javac options: -source 1.8 and -target 1.8. The problem occurs on both Windows and Linux.

**The basic question is why `addressToBytes` method does not always return the same result?**
Sometimes instead of expected array: [4, 10, 10, 10, 10] some part of address is replaced with 0. For example: [4, 10, 10, 10, 0]

Here is the code you can use to reproduce the problem:

```
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.net.InetSocketAddress

object RaceCondition {

  class SomeOutputStream(val data: Array[Byte], var currentIndex: Int) extends OutputStream {
    override def write(bytes: Array[Byte], off: Int, len: Int): Unit = {
      System.arraycopy(bytes, off, data, currentIndex, len)
      currentIndex += bytes.length
    }

    def write(b: Int): Unit = {
      data.update(currentIndex, b.toByte)
      currentIndex += 1
    }
  }

  def addressToBytes(sAddress: InetSocketAddress): Array[Byte] = {
    val result: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](sAddress.getAddress.getAddress.length + 1)
    val writer = new SomeOutputStream(result, 0)
    val addressBytes = sAddress.getAddress.getAddress
    writer.write(addressBytes.length)
    writer.write(addressBytes)
    writer.data
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var i = 0
    val expected = Array[Byte](4, 10, 10, 10, 10)
    val address = new InetSocketAddress("10.10.10.10", 1234)
    var count = 0
    var lastOk = true
    while (i < 1000000) {
      i += 1
      val data = addressToBytes(address)
      if (!data.sameElements(expected)) {
        count += 1
        if(lastOk){
          println(s"\n\nBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD $i\n\n")
        }
        lastOk = false
      } else {
        if(!lastOk){
          println(s"\n\nGOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOD $i\n\n")
        }
        lastOk = true
      }
    }
    println(s"Failures: $count")
  }
}
```

Comment: If it works with -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=3 then it suggests that you may be running into a server compiler (C2) bug. Can you run your test with the latest JDK 11 build to see if the issue exists? If it does then submit a bug to bugs.sun.com with the details on how to reproduce it. Make sure to include info on the processor as it may be relevant to the issue.